# android register device returns server unavailable

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

using wso2 emm 2.0.0 running on aws
I could not find the emm page to send a registration email to a device. I used the QR barcode to get the url to request the android agent APK download. The aPK downloads and installs. I open the apk, I entered the server ip and default port 9443, blank domain, admin user, admin password, byod. I get a server unavailable error.

Comment: are there any errors in wso2carbon.log? you will explicitly send the email. After you configure email configurations and when you create the user, email will automatically send to the user mail.

Comment: The system cannot infer the transport information from the mailto

Comment: put 9763 instead of 9443 and check?

Comment: using port 9763, the response is "Incorrect login information". The domain was blank, the username was the same as the username for the new user that was added by the admin in the emm add user. The password was foo.

Comment: http_access log "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 400 92 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"

Answer (score 0):

You must have provided the wrong server IP and port. If you have used HTTPS port as default, you won't be able to register because if you want HTTPS to work, you must follow [1] to get it done.

So just use server URL as follows.

SERVER URL : :9763 (ex : 10.10.10.250:9763)

Login as follows,

USERNAME : admin 
PASSWORD : admin

You can keep the Domain field empty.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Android+Configurations